# copy file content using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I am looking to copy txt file content to clipboard so that I will be able to paste it somewhere else (using MAC terminal). Normally, I am supposed to select the text content and make a copy. That is not convenient in my case since the content is too large too scrolled all the way down. Is there a Linux shortcut that I can use to copy the content within a single command? I have heard about `cat`, yet that did not work in my case.

Comment: Are you using mac or linux?

Comment: @mikep I am using mac

Answer (score 9):

Use [pbcopy](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html):

```
cat myfile.txt | pbcopy
```

[More examples.](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/05/manipulating-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: I am having hard type pasting the content ... its not working

Answer (score -1):

On a mac, you can click on the terminal and Cmd-A, or go to Edit->select all, to select everything.  Then Cmd-C to copy and Cmd-V to paste.

EDIT:  To copy a file, open the file in TextEdit and do as above.

Comment: the problem is when I do cmd-a, it copies everything including all the command lines(contents) I used starting from the time I opens the terminal

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: Wait: you want to copy the contents of a file?

Comment: ya, but like ... do you think there is working solution which can be applied terminal?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if its the best option, but you can use:

```
nano fileName.txt
```

and then use your mouse (left) to copy partial or entire contents. And then right click and "Copy."

This will work if `cat` is not working for you.